# Spring boot - UnsatisfiedDependencyException when using JPA to store and retrieve data in a relational database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I've tried to build an application that uses Spring Data JPA to store and retrieve data in a relational database using Spring boot. I've been following guide on the spring site but continue to get this error. Does anyone know the cause of this or what I could do to fix it? Would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commandLine' defined in com.example.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.example.ImageRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'imageRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#391c56d7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#391c56d7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#391c56d7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#391c56d7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

The code is below:

The repository:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

 public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

     List<Image> findByImageID(long imageID);
}
```

The application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLine(ImageRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            repository.save(new Image("image1",50,40));
            repository.save(new Image("image2",50,40));
            repository.save(new Image("image3",50,40));
            repository.save(new Image("image4",50,40));
            repository.save(new Image("image5",50,40));

            log.info("Customers found with findAll():");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for (Image image : repository.findAll()) {
                log.info(image.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            Image image = repository.findOne(1L);
            log.info("Image found with findOne(1L):");
            log.info("--------------------------------");
            log.info(image.toString());
            log.info("");

            log.info("Image found with findByImageID(1):");
            log.info("--------------------------------------------");
            for (Image im : repository.findByImageID(1)) {
                log.info(im.toString());
            }
            log.info("");
        };
    }
}
```

The entity

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long imageID;
    private double lat, lon;
    private String description = "";

    protected Image() {}

    Image(String description, double lat, double lon)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;

    }
    Image(double lat, double lon)
    {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public long getID()
    {
        return imageID;
    }
    public String getDesc()
    {
        return description;
    }
    public double getLat()
    {
        return lat;
    }
    public double getLon()
    {
        return lon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Image[id=%d, description='%s', lat='%d', lon='%d']",
                imageID, description,lat,lon);
    }

}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you have the dependencies to spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and some db driver?

Comment: See Spring tutorial about that. It is pretty awsome: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: That's the guide I used, did everything the same but it doesn't work

Comment: I had the dependency for spring-data-jpa instead of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Could be my problem? Think it's caused another error now in my pom so going to try fix it and get back to you.

Comment: Your maven pom.xml? How dies it look? It seams that there is no bean for an entitymanagerfactory. So your jpa library does somehow not provide it or there is just none of it in the classpath.

Comment: I'll update the post with my pom.xml now, thanks

Comment: Can you replace spring-data-jpa AND persistence-api with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa? If you get an error then. Which one?

Comment: I get an error at this time of the pom.xml  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

which says Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final

and Failure to transfer org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final

Comment: Uh. Cant try it on my own now. Will try it later and provide an answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: By changeing the dependencies maven wanted to download more artifact which obviously caused some trouble. You should try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I had the time to test it on my machine. The problem is that you are missing a jpa implementation. By adding a dependency to spring-data-jpa and and persistence-api you only get the interfaces. If you replace those two dependencies with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, you will actually get a hibernate entitymanager implementation.

This is the pom.xml I successfully tested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```